# how to draw text on image view android

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I have an app that calculate time of phone usage and you can share it on social networks, instead of normal `gettext()` I want to put the results on an image and save it to phone. How can I create an image that I can save to the phone that includes custom text?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Nobody here will write your app for you.

Comment: Do you need to show your Image on screen, or just save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to paint to a Canvas that's linked to a Bitmap, and save the bitmap. Here's a few bits of code that you should be able to string together to make it work. Note that you'll have to still add the paining to the canvas, in the `getBitmap()` function.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap() {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPieToss.getWidth(),
            mPieToss.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    // Draw things to your canvas. They will be included as your BitMap, which is saved later on


    return bitmap;
}

public void save() {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap();

    File path = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());

    String filename = "Imagen_" + timestamp + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(path, filename);
    FileOutputStream stream;
    // This can fail if the external storage is mounted via USB
    try {
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all convert your layout to bitmap:

```
View contentLayout; // your layout with bavkground image and TextView
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

content.draw(canvas);
```

Now you can save it to the file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName, false);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, fos);

fos.flush();
fos.close();
```